# How to remove columns from a file by given the columns in anther file in Linux?

Tags: bash, awk

Suppose I have a file A contains the column numbers need to be removed (I really have over 500 columns in my input file fileB),

fileA:

```
2
5
```

And I want to remove those columns(2 and 5) from fileB:

```
a b c d e f
g h i j k l
```

in Linux to get:

```
a c d f
g i j l
```

what should I do? I found out that I could eliminate printing those columns with the code:

```
awk '{$2=$5="";print $0}' fileB
```

however, there are two problems in this way, first it does not really remove those columns, it just using empty string to replace them; second, instead of manually typing in those column numbers, how can I get these column numbers by reading from another file.

---

Original Question:
Suppose I have a file A contains the column numbers need to be removed,

file A:

223
345
346
567

And I want to remove those columns(223, 345,567) from file B in Linux, what should I do?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I found out that I could eliminate printing those columns with the code:  awk '{$223=$345=$346=$567="";print $0}' fileB, however, there are two problems in this way, first it does not really remove those columns, it just using empty string to replace them; second, instead of manually typing in those column numbers, how can I get these column numbers by reading from another file.

Comment: Add that information to your question, don't put it in a comment where it can't be formatted and could be missed. And talking of formatting, please use the "code blocks" info from https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to format your sample input, expected output, and code.

Comment: We don't want to see an example that has over 567 columns. Please create and post a [mcve] with, say, 6 columns where you want to delete 2 of them. Once you get an answer for that, you can apply the same technique to your real problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `cut` have the `--complement` option then you can do:

```sh
cut --complement -d ' ' -f "$(echo $(<FileA))" fileB
```

Comment: Fravadona, I have one more question, I found out that if fileA was empty which means there is no column needs to be removed, then instead of return the fileB, it returns nothing. Do you know how to make it return the fileB? Thank you!

Comment: @MengnaZhang I would test FileA before running the command: `[ -s FileA ] && cut --complement ...`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    badFldNrs[$1]
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        if ( !(inFldNr in badFldNrs) ) {
            out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
        }
    }
}
{
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
        printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk fileA fileB
a c d f
g i j l
```

Comment: Very nice. Save the ones you want and skip those you don't.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin right, this way if you want to output 10 out of 100 fields then the main loop iterates 10 times instead of 100 as would happen with [markp-fuso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70408493/1745001) and [HatLess's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70408685/1745001). I figure since the OP has over 500 fields and a whole file of fields to skip efficiency probably matters.

Comment: @EdMorton - that is a (not so) subtle point I didn't clue into until your comment. A well placed comment never hurts to emphasize an important point that may have escaped the slow old folks on first glance.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I feel like I post this sort of code about once a week, I just get lazy about explaining why until if/when someone comments on it.

Answer (score 3):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { skip[$1] ; next }                # store field #s to be skipped
        { line=""                          # initialize output variable
          pfx=""                           # first prefix will be ""
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)              # loop through the fields in this input line ...
              if ( !(i in skip) ) {        # if field # not mentioned in the skip[] array then ...
                 line=line pfx $i          # add to our output variable
                 pfx=OFS                   # prefix = OFS for 2nd-nth fields to be added to output variable
              }
          if ( pfx == OFS )                # if we have something to print ...
             print line                    # print output variable to stdout
         }
' fileA fileB
```

**NOTE:** OP hasn't provided the input/output field delimiters; OP can add the appropriate `FS/OFS` assignments as needed

This generates:

```
a c d f
g i j l
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {col[$1]=$1;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if (i != col[i]) printf("%s ", $i);  printf("\n")}' fileA fileB
a c d f
g i j l
```